# How can I make the debugger force a Windows thread to wake up from sleep?

Tags: windows, multithreading, debugging, condition-variable

I'm debugging a deadlock.  I would like to wake up a thread that's waiting on a condition variable, so that I can trace as it re checks the sleep conditions.  Sleeping on a condition variable is subject to spurious wake ups, so how can I force such a wake up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using windbg you can call WakeAllConditionVariable in the debugee using windbg's `.call` command.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio, but your suggestion may work using the immediate window.  A con is that all threads are woken up, not only the interesting one.

Comment: With windbg you can first suspend all the non-interesting threads (while they are blocked in the SleepConditionVariable* call) using `~n` and then issue the `.call` command. Now, only the interesting thread will wake up.